# what is ( ) => void callback function in chrome documentation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am reading chrome documentation for my extension. I see a lot of methods like this:

```
chrome.scripting.insertCSS(
    injection: CSSInjection,
    callback?: function
)
```

And it says about callback?: function

```
// The callback function parameter look like this:
() => void
```

This is my code and I'm trying to put CSS in any website i visit to make the all paragraph red

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
let text = chrome.scripting.insertCSS({target: {tabId: tabs[0].id}, files: ['css.css']}, () => {})
})
```

The css.css is my external file to make all the paragraph red in any website i visit like this:

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

My code works. It can make the paragraph red in every website i visit. But my question is: what is the use of () => void function parameter in the chrome documentation I always see and how can i utilize this?

I tried to imitate what is in documentation. But I still cannot understand how () => void works and how to utilize it. Can anyone help me to understand this in a simple way?

Comment: `() => void` Is a function that takes no arguments and returns no value. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#functions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#functions

Comment: `() => void` is not a valid JavaScript expression IIUC. It might be used in documentation to indicate a function that returns `undefined`, or it might be valid TypeScript syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback to know when the CSS insertion is complete.

```js
chrome.scripting.insertCSS({ target: { tabId: tabs[0].id }, files: ['css.css'] }, () => {
  console.log("Finished inserting the CSS.");
});

console.log("The CSS insertion is probably not complete.");
```

I have a suggestion for you.
You will be happier with content_scripts.

```json
{
  "name": "content_scripts",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [
        "matches.css"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.css

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i'm glad it works now. btw how can i be happier with content_scripts?